# Drop down menu without any module

Tags: routes

Hello is it possible to create drop down menu without using any plugins at all?
In general the structure of menu is as follows for drop down.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Top1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">drop1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">drop2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

I have create new menu and placed menu parents and children accordingly. Now I need to know if it is possible to show the menu in structure as above without using third-party modules.

Comment: Allergy about plug-ins? :) Do you want to do it without using Superfish or NiceMenu.

Comment: yes @ShoaibNawaz

Comment: I tried to use menu tree but it is only showing top level menus

Comment: Then this question re related about JS/JQuery.

Comment: was unable to answer own question. but follwing worked.
    <?php $menu = menu_tree('menu name');
 print render( $menu ); ?>
Above code worked. Plus had to make show as expanded in menu management.

Comment: What is the Drupal version you are using?

Comment: askkirati Where did you paste the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pure CSS, here is a tutorial: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/ You can find several more if you google for CSS dropdown menu.

You will need to set up your menu, clicking on the "expanded" checkbox for any submenus you want to render.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. As "Shoaib Nawaz" said in the comments, you can use Javascript (jQuery) to convert the list into a dropdown.
2. I don't know why you don't want to use any plugins (I suppose you mean "module")?
   But if it's fine for you to create your own module, there is another solution:

   - Create a module
   - Overwrite the function [theme_menu_tree](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7) to convert the "ul" into "select"
   - Overwrite the function [theme_menu_link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) to convert the "li" into "option"
   - Bonus: If you don't want to overwrite every menus, you can overwrite only a specific menu using `[MODULE]_menu_link__[MENU NAME]`.